# Error in executing task: 'javax.jms.Session javax.jms.Connection.createSession(boolean, int)

Tags: oracle, jar, wso2, queue, oracle-aq

I followed this [blog](https://medium.com/@shefandarren.173/configuring-oracle-aq-with-wso2-enterprise-integrator-54d14461ca78) and tried to configure Oracle AQ with WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.2.0. There I created proxy service and inbound endpoint as explined in the blog. But I'm getting the below error.

```
ERROR {TaskQuartzJobAdapter} - Error in executing task: 'javax.jms.Session javax.jms.Connection.createSession(boolean, int)' java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.jms.Session javax.jms.Connection.createSession(boolean, int)'
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.jms.factory.JMSConnectionFactory.createSession(JMSConnectionFactory.java:469)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.jms.factory.CachedJMSConnectionFactory.createSession(CachedJMSConnectionFactory.java:113)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.jms.factory.CachedJMSConnectionFactory.getSession(CachedJMSConnectionFactory.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.jms.JMSPollingConsumer.poll(JMSPollingConsumer.java:246)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.jms.JMSPollingConsumer.execute(JMSPollingConsumer.java:203)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.jms.JMSTask.taskExecute(JMSTask.java:46)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.common.InboundTask.execute(InboundTask.java:43)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.mediation.ntask.NTaskAdapter.execute(NTaskAdapter.java:105)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:63)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I added below jars to the lib and using oracle 12c docker image for the testing.

- aqapi-11.1.1.2.0.jar
- jta-1.1.jar
- jmscommon-9i.jar
- ojdbc7.jar

Any idea about this issue and the way to resolve this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an incompatible version of Jars. Try updating the `aqapi.jar` and `jmscommons.jar` to the latest version as in [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/aqapi/11.2.0.0) and [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/jmscommon/1.1.0.0).

First, delete the Jars you already added from `<MI_HOME>/lib` and `<MI_HOME>/droppings` directories and then add the new jars.

Comment: When I tried to get the jars from the provided Maven repo, it gave 400 Bad Requests.

Comment: Any idea where I can download the correct jars?

Comment: @L.Malsha It seems there is a newer version as well. Try this one https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.messaging/aqapi/23.2.0.0

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was able to find the correct old jars from the different repo.